# tsCV auto.arima with xreg results in NAs

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation

I'm using the tsCV function from the forecast package in R. I'm comparing arima with and without xreg. Without xreg I have no problems. But when I add xreg to the tsCV function I get a matrix of NAs.

I thought I might need length(xreg) = length(y) + horizon. But if I do that I get an error: xreg must be of the same size as y.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'xts':
#>   method     from
#>   as.zoo.xts zoo
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'forecast':
#>   method             from    
#>   fitted.fracdiff    fracdiff
#>   residuals.fracdiff fracdiff

stack_data <- ts(rnorm(100), start = 2000, frequency = 12)
stack_data_xreg <- ts(rnorm(100), start = 2000, frequency = 12)


farma <- function(x, h){forecast(auto.arima(x), h = h)}
tsCV(stack_data, farma)
#>              Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May
#> 2000  0.40563034  0.17463799 -0.77045150 -1.26653788 -0.54549741
#> 2001 -0.82662134 -0.12712224 -0.16689046 -0.28039922 -0.14633838
#> 2002  1.00869308 -0.10646429 -0.11733494 -0.98269977  2.02888513
#> 2003  0.08992425 -0.04478466  1.33947694  0.61512603 -1.47779195
#> 2004  0.62197916 -0.31285023 -1.87748218  0.05545157  0.79404086
#> 2005  1.34079217  1.16067205 -0.31473379  1.28361957  0.26702644
#> 2006 -0.20387530  0.14089200  0.09655947 -1.68903183 -1.74576484
#> 2007 -1.47340231  2.07289246 -1.88595924 -0.08185593  0.66826102
#> 2008  1.46971617  0.56345483 -1.39370468          NA            
#>              Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct
#> 2000  0.03088558 -1.56988024  0.36739705  0.19510088  0.35736462
#> 2001  0.61791686 -0.34181673 -0.38493804  1.65816962 -0.09582700
#> 2002 -1.40810233 -1.49081572  0.45128015 -0.22893364  0.14057981
#> 2003 -1.18764843  0.05096855  1.36152907 -0.11422859  0.27291010
#> 2004  1.85680313  1.88050368 -1.03857395 -1.92289436  1.04696123
#> 2005  1.03188951  0.89751963  1.92407988  1.35389806  0.89851252
#> 2006 -0.01003884  0.70429687 -0.71814159 -0.42640676  1.37978749
#> 2007 -1.19165002  1.02750038 -0.23383838 -0.76811251  1.02074594
#> 2008                                                            
#>              Nov         Dec
#> 2000  1.19798923  1.59771830
#> 2001  0.68061128  0.59334251
#> 2002  0.41844484 -0.90827529
#> 2003  0.05572988 -1.41338097
#> 2004  1.21183965  0.82382650
#> 2005  0.63131654  1.40116039
#> 2006  0.13046189 -1.71495153
#> 2007 -1.62466898  0.63538448
#> 2008
tsCV(stack_data, farma, xreg = stack_data_xreg)
#>      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#> 2000  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2001  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2002  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2003  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2004  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2005  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2006  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2007  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2008  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I tried to change my farma function as follows:
`farma_x <- function(x, h, xreg){forecast(auto.arima(x, xreg = xreg), h = h)}`

but that did not work.

I have no problem when I run auto.arima with xreg, only when I try to use tsCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the `xreg` matrix into two pieces, one used for training and one for forecasting. The following code should fix the problem.

```r
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
stack_data <- ts(rnorm(100), start = 2000, frequency = 12)
stack_data_xreg <- ts(rnorm(100), start = 2000, frequency = 12)

farma <- function(y, h, xreg) {
  ncol <- NCOL(xreg)
  X <- matrix(xreg[seq_along(y), ], ncol = ncol)
  if (NROW(xreg) < length(y) + h) {
    stop("Not enough xreg data for forecasting")
  }
  newX <- matrix(xreg[length(y) + seq(h), ], ncol = ncol)
  fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg = X)
  forecast(fit, xreg = newX, h = h)
}

tsCV(stack_data, farma, xreg = stack_data_xreg)
#>               Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May
#> 2000  0.810097135           NA  1.304257208  0.682981005 -5.610649793
#> 2001 -2.300753372  1.122943604 -0.056166686 -0.024771800  0.936527913
#> 2002 -0.083400817 -0.153262209 -1.469429055 -0.451752087  0.436745959
#> 2003 -0.021221494  1.147379540  0.765396693 -0.093538812 -0.305109643
#> 2004  0.951795652  0.395926226 -0.611855910  0.344129361 -1.123042184
#> 2005 -0.051414670  0.743490403  0.059981832 -0.765007510  0.247113268
#> 2006 -0.935160311 -1.365429702  0.291221704 -0.438080942  0.025365086
#> 2007  0.336816520  1.028414077 -0.271960523  0.389200605  0.306516552
#> 2008 -0.713072219 -1.223829836 -0.476239935           NA             
#>               Jun          Jul          Aug          Sep          Oct
#> 2000  0.525713374  0.722321499  0.527858032 -0.569519802  1.544766085
#> 2001  0.844427791  0.591343448  0.907552931  0.859488240  0.078810418
#> 2002  1.355720366 -0.070836700  0.357486229  0.049680596 -1.396737647
#> 2003  0.748322301  0.551776497 -0.709934151 -0.702899128  0.317519688
#> 2004  1.480106472  1.960889994 -0.302600323 -1.088335143  0.491245564
#> 2005 -1.809366181  1.451960439  0.147030897  2.181626321  0.558826680
#> 2006  0.085603679 -0.577727812 -0.592174595 -0.125793946  1.180536801
#> 2007 -0.535583516  1.191666401  1.194077284  0.670606300  1.637822904
#> 2008                                                                 
#>               Nov          Dec
#> 2000  0.366156757 -0.522869056
#> 2001 -1.986002110  0.624077286
#> 2002 -0.350771686 -0.374158943
#> 2003  0.767824690 -0.059505618
#> 2004 -0.002975468  2.431699557
#> 2005 -0.708162439  0.618942712
#> 2006 -1.534986325  0.583242325
#> 2007  0.437497859 -1.456253804
#> 2008
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank yo so much. This worked.